# Pythonic update of a `defaultdict`

Tags: python

What is a more "pythonic" version of this code? (in Python 2.x)

```
from collections import defaultdict
dd = defaultdict(list)
for i in some_list_of_items:
    current_dict = dict_from_an_item(i)
    for (k, v) in current_dict.items():
        dd[k].extend(v)
```

the `dict_from_an_item` parses an item and returns a dict that contains not nested lists as the values. Something like this    :

```
{ 'key1': [1, 2, 3],
  'key2': [2, 3, 4],
  'key3': [3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]}
```

Comment: What does `dict_from_an_item` do?

Comment: How deep are the dict structures? Is `for (k, v) in current_dict.values():` really what you want? Key/Value pairs are returned with `.items()`, not `.values()`.

Comment: "Code-golf" and "pythonic way" are frequently exclusive constraints, aren't they. Code-golf results in unreadable source and that's definitely not any of Python principles.

Comment: See the edited version. Hope is clearer now. Also removed the "code golf" remark

Comment: And what does `some_list_of_items` look like? What does an item look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could spare the `current_dict` variable. Also `k, v` is more pythonic than `(k, v)`

```
from collections import defaultdict

dd = defaultdict(list)
for i in some_list_of_items:
    for k, v in dict_from_an_item(i).iteritems():
        dd[k].extend(v)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need a `defaultdict` for performance reasons you could do:

```
d = {k:v for i in some_list_of_items for k, v in dict_from_an_item(i).iteritems()}
```